# Pycaret compare_models() function does not show output in Jupyter Notebook within VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, vscode-extensions, pycaret

I am seeing difference in behavior of the function compare_models() between how it runs on my Jupyter Notebooks via Anaconda vs Jupyter Notebook within VS Code.

When I execute in the former, the call of compare_models() in a cell returns a color formatted grid of all models and their cross-validates scores. However, when I execute the same code in Juptyter within VS code, I see that scoring grid is not returned. I am forced to use the pull() function to display the grid but that makes all the color formatting of the top scores disappear.

Is there a reason why the scoring grid doesn't work by default in Jupyter within VS Code? What do I need to do to fix it?